# Namespaces or prefixes for controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

I have two Devise models (Doctor and Patient) in my app. And i have two different sets of controllers for each one. At the moment i just prefixing each controller like this:
PatientRegistrationsController, DoctorRegistrationsController etc.

But now i'm thinking about using namespaces for better app organization and structure. For example, Patient::RegistrationsController, Doctor::SessionsController.

Help me deciding which strategy i should use with my controllers - namespaces or prefixing names. Is where any gotchas with namespaces?

Comment: Use namespaces, plural so they don't collide with models: Patients::RegistrationsController, Doctors::SessionsController. I usually do this, and add all controllers for that section in the corresponding namespace

Comment: Thanks alot! One question: do you have any experience with namespaces playing together with InheritedResources gem?

Comment: As i see, there is some problems described here http://gunnertech.com/2011/09/rails-3-on-namespaces-rspec-and-inherited-resources/

Comment: don't know about InheritedResources but I had used this with ActiveScaffold (similar to InheritedResources but more involved) and all was ok, with a little tweaks, source code reading and monkeypatching (not for everyone)

Answer (score 1):

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

You can put the controllers in seperate folders and access them via a different route...

f.e..

```
namespace :doctor do
  resources :data_entries
end
# => http://test.com/doctor/data_entries
# => controller is in app/doctor/data_entries_controller.rb

namespace :patient do
  resources :data_entries
end
# => http://test.com/patient/data_entries
# => controller is in app/patient/data_entries_controller.rb
```